# tf-idf score by query Lucene 5.1

Tags: java, lucene

I can run Lucene 5.1 for sorting documents in a folder based on a given query by using "`org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles`" and "`org.apache.lucene.demo.SearchFiles`".

However I need to query a word or term and get `tf-idf` (or at least IDF) score as output.

**Second question**: does **Lucene** detect the model based on the query?

For example if the query being a bi-gram or trigram then **Lucene** will create a bigram or trigram model?

Comment: what do you want to do? it's not clear? could you explain it with some basic example?

Comment: @Mysterion I'm going to build my feature vector for classification and one of my feature is tf-idf. For example i need to give the query "you have" and Lucene return its tf-idf score to me.